# Pseudo Code - Place finder Python

Tags: python, pseudocode

I am trying to understand "Pseudo code"; a language often used by developers before they proceed to code in Python. So I was wondering how I would convert this into Pseudo code.

```
sentence= input("Enter a sentence")
lower = sentence.lower()
keyword= input("Input a keyword from the sentence")
twolower= keyword.lower()
words = lower.split(' ')
for (i, subword) in enumerate(words):
    if (subword == twolower): 
        print(i+1)
```

The program in question has to take an inputted sentence and then take a word and tell the user where the word appears in that sentence.

Comment: Pseudo code isn't a defined thing. You can write it however you want.

Comment: 1. get input from a user. 2. Lowercase the sentence. 3. get a keyword from the user. 4. lowercase the keyword. 5. get the words in the sentence. 6. loop over the words - if any of them is the keyword, print it's position

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code is not a defined language; it is a convenient description in natural language.  The level of detail changes with the application; the wording will change with individual and audience.

Simply write a less formal description of what you're doing at each stage, such as

```
Prompt the user for a sentence and a keyword.
Convert both to lower-case.
```

Does that give you the general idea?

Comment: Yep that's great thank you! I'm slightly confused though as to the section where the sentence is split up, would I just write "Split the sentence into individual words" or something along those lines?

Comment: Yes; that wording would do just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write psuedo code in any way that fits your style or needs.

For example, this could be written as:

1. get sentence input from user
2. change sentence to lowercase
3. get keyword input from user
4. change keyword to lowercase
5. get words in sentence
6. loop over words, checking if each word is the same as keyword, and if so, printing the position of the word

Comment: @Calum: here's a good example of my initial point: Zach has described your first four lines individually; I combined them and shortened the wording.  Each is perfectly valid pseudo-code.  Mine is shorter and perhaps easier to grasp quickly; Zach's is something you can directly translate to Python code. /// At a higher level of abstraction, the pseudo-code could easily be a two-line version of your question's final sentence.